# How to delete a specific line from file using sed

Tags: sed, syntax

When I try to delete a specific line number from my file, all lines that have the same pattern are deleted. This is not what I want, I want to only delete the line number itself, not similar patterns.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
x = 5
```

Command I run now:

```
sed -i "${x}d" home/file.txt
```

Comment: Did you try `x=5`, (without spaces)

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You had spaces around your variable assignment

`x = 5`

Which would be wrong.

Try the below fix

`x=5`

`sed -i ${x}d home/file.txt`

Comment: (i) That is an option only inside a shell function.  (ii) That has the same syntax error that the OP's does.  (iii) It's unclear why you think declaring the variable local would make a difference.  (iv) It would have been wise to try that out before posting it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger declaring the variable locally actually does'nt make a difference.

Comment: Yes, exactly so.  So that leaves this answer saying what?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The code been edited , there wasnt supposed to be spaces around the equality sign

Comment: @JohnBollinger the Purpose of the question would be acheived by the code i posted and the code the owner of the question was trying to ask only that he would need to remove the spaces around his equal sign when he did  `x = 5`

Comment: That would be a good thing to write in this answer in place of "try make the x variable a local one".  It's also unclear what Terminal has to do with it -- shell scripts are not specific to Terminal (and that specific name is a Mac thing).

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're very right. I would improve in making my answers more purposeful. As terminal is for mac and could get other viewers confused

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to delete line number 33 of your file:

```sh
 sed -i '33d' home/file.txt
```

If you need the number to be a variable:

```sh
local line_number=5 

sed -i "${line_number}d" home/file.txt
```

The problem with what you are doing is the spaces, `x = 5`, will not work while `x=5` will.

Comment: `bash` says: *local: can only be used in a function*

Comment: it works with zsh, but in case you are using plain bash just remove local and it should work

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what I am trying to do:
>
> ```
> x = 5
> ```

That gives me:

> bash: x: command not found...

, which is what I would expect.  If you did not get a similar error message then you must be in the unfortunate situation of having a program named `x` in your path, perhaps because of doing something unwise, such as putting `.` in your `PATH`. Or perhaps you got such a message but did not see it because you have redirected your stderr.<sup>*</sup>

In any event, the quoted line *does not* assign a value to any shell variable.  Shell variable assignments must not have whitespace around the `=` operator, so if you want to assign `5` to variable `x`, that must be

```
x=5
```

.

It is not an error to perform parameter expansion on a name that has not been assigned any value.  The result is nothing.  Thus, if `x` has not successfully been assigned any value then `"${x}d"` will expand to `"d"`.  As a complete `sed` script, that will delete every line.

---

<sup>*</sup>Or if you *did* get such an message then why in the world didn't you at least say so?